# Connecting MongoDB to the front-end?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've built a database with `Node.js` and `MongoDB`, and I'm writing an `Angular.js` app that should call in entries from my database, as well as being able to write in those entries.

I'm aware that there are some security issues with writing directly from javascript to a database, but I'm completely new to this sort of thing. What's more, I can't find any instructions on how to send data from `MongoDB` to my front-end so that I can actually use it!

How do I tie the two together? In `Node.js`, I was using a javascript `require` function to load in my database and read/write from it, but I can't figure out a way to do this in the browser. In `node` I was using the `mongojs`module to connect the two together, but this doesn't work in my Angular app as I can't use `require`.

**The main question is: How do I load in MongoDB to the front-end?**

EDIT: I think this is a more basic question about calling MongoDB to the front-end, rather than angular-specific. If I'm wrong, let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to connect from browser directly to database? This is a **very** bad idea. That's exactly why you want to use NodeJS (or any other web server): you load data from DB to WebServer and then combine it there into HTML/JSON/any format you want and then send it to browser via HTTP.

Comment: What problems did you have trying to require the mongojs module on the frontend? You'll need a module loader such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Short answer:** You don't.

**Long answer:** MongoDB isn't designed to expose data directly to the client. The client interacts with the application on the webserver - in your case implemented in Node.js - and the webserver communicates with the database.

```
+---------+    +---------+    +---------+ 
|Browser  |    | Node.js |    | MongoDB | 
|        ------->        |    |         |    
|         |    |         |    |         |
|         |    |        ------->        |
|         |    |         |    |         |
|         |    |         |    |         |
|         |    |        <-------        |    
|         |    |         |    |         |   
|        <-------        |    |         | 
|         |    |         |    |         |  
+---------+    +---------+    +---------+
```

This means in practice, that the javascript client application executed in the users browser sends a request to Node.js (via a normal page request, via XmlHttpRequest via Websockets or some other method). Node.js accepts this request and then contacts MongoDB for the data required to fulfill it. When Node.js received the data from the database, it uses it to build the response, and sends it to the client.

The client application doesn't realize that the server used a backend database to fulfill the request.

**My learning recommendation for you** is to leave the database out for now. Use angular.js to make the client load some static data from the Node.js server application. When you got this working, extend the server-side to obtain the data from MongoDB.

Comment: I've actually done your learning recommendation already - the AngularJS app I've written loads in data via JSON. The issue is, I really don't understand (nor have I been able to find in my quite extensive searching) how to link up the DB to the frontend. I'm happy to use node as a middleman, but I've never seen any implementations where the client -> node -> db. Can you suggest any resources where I can learn more about this? I'm primarily a frontend dev so a lot of this is way over my head.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was written a long time ago, so if you are in the future/now — you may look at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/react-web-quickstart/ which lets browser-based applications access data stored in MongoDB Atlas and interact with App Services services like Functions and authentication.