# Access MongoDB using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an HTML 5 / Javscript application saves data in MongoDB using C# web services.
I believe we can access MongoDB using Node js . SO this is like accessing MongoDB using javscript.
How do I invoke the data-access script from the frontend, say on click of a button. Right now, this button click invokes a C# web service. 
I can run the data-access script in the unix terminal after typing node and then the script name. But how do I bridge the gap between my frontend and backend; bring the two under one ecosystem ?
On click of a button, this script (that acsesses mongodb) needs to be invoked.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate question

I think you can refer to [javascript - Connecting MongoDB to the front-end? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469237/connecting-mongodb-to-the-front-end)

Philipp has good explanation xD

Comment: There are LOTS of tutorials on the web using the web services to access MongoDB via Node.JS. Do you have a specific programming question about code you've written?

Comment: If it is about accessing MongoDB via Node JS , then why do we need a web service? That is what I am looking for. Node JS could run a script that would access MongoDB, but hot do I invoke this script using the front-end Javscript ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to [javascript - Connecting MongoDB to the front-end? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469237/connecting-mongodb-to-the-front-end)

Philipp has good explanation xD

Just to add a little bit on *why you can't use your MongoDB (or DB) from frontend*.

You'll need **a driver** to connect, and that's not included in your web browsers js engine.

Know more:

- [mongodb/node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)
- [Node.js MongoDB Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/)

Comment: The one you have referred me to is also unanswered in a way.I know how to access mongoDB using  node JS. What I want to know is how do I use node to access mongo DB from my front end. Say , I click a button and it should lead to MongoDB being access (using the Node JS ofcourse). But how does Node Js get integrated with my frontend.

Comment: Yea. Sorry about that. So you'll need a driver. And that's not provided by your frontend (user's web browsers).