# How can I add Collection on mongoDB by clicking button on frontend?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am building a Chat application where I need to add more rooms(groups). I have used MongoDB for the database.

This is my Schema.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema( {
      message: String,
      name: String,
      timestamp: String,
      received: Boolean,
});

const messageContent = mongoose.model('messageContent', Schema);
                                
export default messageContent;
```

I can add Collections easily by going on Mongodb.com but I want to add it by using a button on the frontend.

This is frontend where I have made a button and onClicking it, a prompt comes and we have to write the room name. But after that, my code is giving me an error.

```js
import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import "./SidebarChat.css";
import Schema from "./messages";

function SidebarChat({adddNewChat}) {

    const db = mongoose.connection;

    const createChat = e => {
        const roomname = prompt("Add a new chat name");

        if(roomname){
            console.log("roomName is created : ", roomname);
            mongoose.model('room', Schema);
        }
    }

    return !adddNewChat ? (
        <div className="sidebarChat">
            <Avatar />
            <div className="sidebarChat__right">
                <h2>Room Name</h2>
                <p>Last Message</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) :
    (
        <div className="sidebarChat" onClick={createChat}>
            <h2> Add new Chat</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SidebarChat
```

Please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: You are mixing your forntend and backend code more insights on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469237/connecting-mongodb-to-the-front-end#:~:text=Short%20answer%3A%20You%20don%27t,your%20case%20implemented%20in%20Node.

Comment: If I remove the backend code from frontend. Then how can I make my functionality fulfilled.

Comment: you will need to use API to communicate between your frontend and mongodb, you can go through the link I sent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not a good way which put react and mongoose together.

It's because "react" expected to be run by browser like firefox, chrome, ...etc.
And those browser doesn't fully support functions from "mongoose" and vice versa.

> Mongoose's browser library does not support saving documents, queries, populate, discriminators, or any other Mongoose feature other than schemas and validating documents.

[Mongoose in browser](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html)

On the other hand, "mongoose" would be run by pure "node.js" which doesn't have a DOM structure to render.