# How to connect MongoDB with VanillaJS?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database-connection

I am trying to make a simple website in VanillaJS. I don't want to do much work on the backend so is there a way to connect your MongoDB database to VanillaJS? I have searched it many times but I can't find an answer to this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this:
[Connecting MongoDB to the front-end?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17471431/16706782)

*@Philipp:*

> **MongoDB isn't designed to expose data directly to the client.**

**Updated:**

I think you can use the cloud services provided by the databases (Like Mongodb Atlas). **[MongoDB Atlas API](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/)**

Comment: So are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: Or should I use some other database like SQL?

Comment: **This is out of security**, but you can create a controller/action function on the back-end and send your commands to execute it ...

Comment: controller/action function (For executing queries directly) - **This is out of security**

Comment: I don't about them, but is there any other database that can connect directly to client?

Answer (score 0):

Client-side JS does not provide any apis for connecting any kinds of DB, it means your DB connection including username and password will be exposed, which means anyone can access your DB.

If you want to have a DB running and with some apis, may try [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)?

Comment: Can firebase be used directly on VanillaJS?

Answer (score 0):

yes firebase can be used in vanillaJS. but having hardtime finding ways to mimick "LIKE %" when querying.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).