# (Angular) How to use a class from JS file in TS file of a component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

## What Am I Doing?

I am trying to use a class `Database` with function `writeDataInDB` in `.component.ts` so I can write data into MongoDB using `ngModel`.

## Issue

I cannot export the class Database, that's it. If this is resolved my app is complete.

## What Have I Tried?

I have tried asking searching StackOverFlow with the keyword "how to use a class from an external JS file in angular", and similar keyword. I even asked ChatGPT and it gave me solutions that does not work, even the ones concerning `tsconfig.json` and `angular.json` didn't work.

## Code

**server.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/users';

mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`MongoDB connection error: ${err}`);
});

db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username,
  email,
  password
})

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

export class DataBase {
  name = ""
  email = ""
  password = "";

  constructor(name, email, passwd) {
    this.name = name
    this.email = email
    this.password = passwd
  }

  async writeDataInDB(name, email, passwd) {
    try {
      // Create a new user document
      const user = new UserModel({
        username: name,
        email: email,
        password: passwd,
      });

      // Save the user document to the 'users' collection
      const savedUser = await user.save();
      console.log('User saved:', savedUser);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error writing data to DB:', error);
    }
  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import * as Database from "src/server.js"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  userData: {username: string, email: string, password: string} = {
    username: "", email: "", password: ""
  }


  addToDatabase(username: string, email: string, password: string) {

  }
}
```

Comment: The question "What have you tried?" primarily means "What **code** have you tried and what problems did you have?".  You say you "cannot export the class"; why? How did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: Unrelated: The phrase "data base" is always a compound word i.e. "database "in the modern English vocabulary, so your class name should be probably renamed to avoid confusion with an object class e.g. "BaseData" (an abstract class or interface representing some generic data).

Comment: You cannot use server-side code on the front-end.

Comment: What I actually have tried? I tried making a TS version of server.js then found out 'require' doesn't work. "Ok, I'll import as mongoose", `(node:2900) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\freed\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Web Development\Angular\login-page\src\server.ts:1
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. I was getting the same error despite doing every correct combination.

Comment: "You cannot use server-side code on the front-end.", how do I use server-side code correctly?

Comment: Please see [Connecting MongoDB to the front-end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469237/connecting-mongodb-to-the-front-end)

Comment: You use server side code correctly by putting it on a server and not on the front end.